# Promises in nodeJS / a callback within a promise / order of executions is not right

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, bluebird

When I am chaining multiple promises and I expect that each promise will execute only after the previous one ended. Somehow it does not happen. I am sure using promises wrong and would love for some explanation.

I have this code:

```
var Promise     = require('bluebird');

func('A')
    .then(() => {func('B')})
    .then(() => {func('C')})
    .then(() => {func('D')})

function func(arg) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
        console.log('>> ' + arg);
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log('  << ' + arg);
            resolve();
        }, 200)
    })
}
```

I was expecting to get this output:

```
>> A
  << A
>> B
  << B
>> C
  << C
>> D
  << D
```

But instead, I get this output:

```
>> A
  << A
>> B
>> C
>> D
  << B
  << C
  << D
```

What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 9):

You need to return the promise

```
func('A')
    .then(() => {return func('B')})
    .then(() => {return func('C')})
    .then(() => {return func('D')})
```

or

```
func('A')
    .then(() => func('B'))
    .then(() => func('C'))
    .then(() => func('D'))
```

---

Ignoring Lexical `this` or Lexical `arguments` part,

`() => {1}` translate to

```
function() { 1 } // return undefined
```

and `() => 1` translate to

```
function() { return 1 }
```